# aws eventbridge eventpattern for opensearch document insert

Tags: opensearch

I want to create a eventbridge rule for triggering aws lambda for every document inserted into opensearch. I need a event pattern for triggering aws lambda based on document insert into opensearch.

I had tried defining the following eventpattern and several other options based on the below template with different syntaxed but nothing is working. I need a event pattern that triggers aws lambda whenever a new document is inserted into aws opensearch.

```
{
    "source": ["aws.es"],
        "account": ["081723753071"],
    "region": ["us-east-1"],
    "resources": ["arn:aws:es:us-east-1:01234563071:domain/cloudwatchevent"],
        "detail-type": ["AWS Opensearch document insert events"],
        "detail": {
        "eventSource": ["es.amazonaws.com"],
        "indexName": ["cloudwatch_events"],
        "eventName": ["IndexDocument"]
    }
}
```